# How can I use other weapons in offline mode?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Sometimes, I'll find myself without internet, and I'll play offline TF2 to brush up some skills.  What I don't like is how I get stuck with stock weapons, and that means I can't work on my Huntsman spammy arrows, or getting Minicrits with the Soda Popper.

Is there any way to use or spawn non-stock weapons in offline mode? It would greatly help me to help improve my experience with my loadouts.

Comment: Have you tried console commands? Found a list online, might be what you need: http://www.8ugaming.com/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Guides/TeamFortress2ConsoleCommands

Comment: You **could** set up a server on your PC and connect to it, though I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @5pike Yes, but those don't have all the weapons available to me.  If I'd like to work on my degreaser/reserve shooter skills, how would I equip those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the only downsides to having server-side items is that you must be connected to the internet to use them. I did manage to create a huntsman training arena without being connected to the internet though. This will work with any item that uses different mechanics from stock (huntsman, mad milk, wrangler, etc.)

1. Click the Create Server button (the little plus sign)
2. Select the map **itemtest**.
3. Once the map loads, join as a Blu Sniper. Press <kbd>F7</kbd> once you've spawned to open the itemtest menu.
4. Click the Sniper check box, give him the huntsman, then click **Apply Test Items**
5. Open the console and type **`tf_bot_add 10 red`**

You are now equipped with the huntsman (with 25 arrows), you are invincible, and you have 10 bots strafing around trying to shoot at you. You can move to the hallway off to the side to camp and practice. I played around with this setup for a good 20 minutes and learned quite a bit with how the huntsman works.

Comment: So, what exactly does F7 do? Does it bring up a bot spawning menu or something?

Comment: F7 is exclusive to itemtest. It brings up a menu that easily allows you to equip any item cosmetically. It's usually used for 3D modelers testing out items after successfully importing them into the game.

Comment: That means I can spawn weapons right? and use them as well, correct?

Comment: Correct, however only the mechanic-changing weapons actually work. For example, the huntsman vs the sniper rifle, or bonk atomic punch vs the pistol. Other weapons that only change attributes (such as the degreaser), look like the weapon but perform identical to the stock flamethrower.

Comment: So are melee weapons considered weapons that change attributes

Comment: All melee weapons act the exact same in itemtest, since there are no 'mechanic-changing' melee weapons. i.e. they all swing and do damage.